# To solve system of linear equations and plotting the graph

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

How to solve and graph the system of linear equations

$$
\begin{aligned}
x-35y &= -30 \\
x+55y &= 25
\end{aligned}
$$

I have to find the point y and plot the lines with the point of intersection of y = 11/18

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eq1 = x - 35 y == -30 
eq2 = x + 55 y == 25

sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eq1 , eq2}, {x, -10, -5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ContourStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.01]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.01]}}, 
 ImageSize -> 200, 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[.05], Point[{x, y} /. First@sol]}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabel -> "Showing the solution to the system"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
sol = Solve[{x - 35 y == -30, x + 55 y == 25}, {x, y}] // N
```

> {{x -> -8.61111, y -> 0.611111}}

```
Plot[{(x + 30)/35, (25 - x)/55}, {x, -12, 3},
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[sol[[1, All, 2]]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`LinearSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) command; i.e, if you have to start with the matrices. It is particularly useful if you have to use the same matrix with a changing `b`.

```
Clear[x, y, m, b];
m = {{1, -35}, {1, 55}};
b = {-30, 25};

sol = LinearSolve[m, b]
```

> {-(155/18), 11/18}

To generate the system:

```
sys = Thread[m . {x, y} == b]
```

> ```
> {x - 35 y == -30, x + 55 y == 25}
> ```

---

Graphics: Here I am plotting the region around this point with a radius of 0.2 that can be changed. This ensures that the point is in the center of the graphic.

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Thread[m . {x, y} == b], {x, y} \[Element] 
  Rectangle[Sequence @@ (Transpose@CoordinateBounds[Circle[sol, 0.2]])]
 , Epilog -> {
   AbsolutePointSize[6]
   , Red, Point@sol
   , Darker@Green, Dashed, Circle[sol, 0.2]
   }
 ]
```

[image]